# Replace all consecutive occurrences of a char with special chars

Tags: c#

I have fill in the blanks form where the length of each blank is not consistent I want to replace such banks with special code to align with business logic, below is how the formats are

```
It is raining ________ in the forest   
The quick _______ dog jumps over ______________ fox
```

I want to reformat above lines as below

```
It is raining [0] in the forest
The quick [0] dog jumps over [1] fox
```

As said the char length of each blank is not consistent, keeping that as case want to write a maintainable code in c# using either regular expression or without

**EXCEPTIONS**

> There are some entries without any blanks in which case should return
>   the whole passage as is

The code suggested by Tim works great my code with Tim's answer is like below. Hope may help someone

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dctE = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> dctT = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string jsonT = string.Empty, jsonH = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\samples\testmongo\testmongo\tamil1.txt"))
        {
            string langs = r.ReadToEnd();
            var lines = langs.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length - 2; i += 2)
            {
                string tml = lines[i].Split(':')[1];
                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"_{2,}");
                    string[] partT = regex.Split(tml);
                    for (int j = 0; j < partT.Length; j++)
                    {
                        tml += partT[j] + "[" + j + "]";
                    }
                //dctE[lines[i].Split(':')[0].Trim()] = lines[i].Split(':')[1].Trim();
                dctT[lines[i - 1].Split(':')[0].Trim()] = tml;// lines[i].Split(':')[1].Trim();
            }

        }
        jsonT = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dctT);

    }
    catch(Exception eX)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eX.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\samples\testmongo\testmongo\ta_yogs.json", jsonT);
        dctE.Clear();
        dctT.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled regularexpression through I am not very good at it guessing may not work since the pattern is inconsistent in my case the length of each blank is irregular

Comment: Can you have an underscore that is **not** to be treated like multiple underscores in your data? I mean, should something like `This is the Id of the item, it's called Item_Id in the database` be valid?

Comment: possible using some sort of `token system` would work. but the tokens would have to be well known to the code to do the replacement (unless you rely solely on a simple sequential replace

Comment: @ZoharPeled I cannot modify existing rules as such would have an impact over other cases

Comment: I wasn't asking to modify the existing rule, I was asking for a clarification. Anyway, Tim already posted a good answer

Comment: @ZoharPeled  got it thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working script.  This approach is to split the input string on *two or more* underscores (`_{2,}`).  Then, we iterate the string components, and join them together into a single string using a numbered `for` loop, using which we can figure out what the replacement placeholders should be.

```
string input = "The quick _______ dog jumps over ______________ fox";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"_{2,}");
string[] parts = regex.Split(input);
string output = "";
for (int i=0; i < parts.Length-1; i++)
{
    output += parts[i] + "[" + i + "]";
}
output += parts[parts.Length-1];
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(output);

The quick _______ dog jumps over ______________ fox
The quick [0] dog jumps over [1] fox
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen works like charm, though I also have a case where there are no blanks in which the code should return the same line as is right now when I tested it returns empty string

Comment: @Naga I [can't reproduce](https://rextester.com/TMN80869) what you are describing.  I get back the original string for the case you mention.

Comment: Sorry, your code works great shall update my question. Just a change needed in my case from parts.Length-1 to parts.Length as it has missed some last tokens. Thanks